# Saving code snippet library in xcode

Tags: xcode, code-snippets

How can one save / restore user created code snippets in Xcode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The user generated code snippets are saved in

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets

And you can simply pass them around to save and restore them.
I recommend giving them a meaningful name instead of the generated one.

I wrote a short explanation about it [here](http://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/adding-custom-code-snippets-extensions/), and also started a collection of useful code snippets that can be shared on [github](https://github.com/adam-siton/AUICodeSnippetsExtensionKit). There are still very little snippets there, so any useful snippets you have to share would be great.

Comment: I do have more code snippets in Xcode, than files in the CodeSnippet folder. Where are the rest saved?

Comment: These last 2 code snippets where from the versions folder `/.DocumentRevisions-V100`. Old versions of changed snippets where shown in Xcode (a bug).